# Send an Email based on the conditions in drupal7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-webform

I have a question reagarding Webforms in drupal7

Scenario:
I have a table in which i have different jobs with repect to locations for example if i select hyderabad locations in the dropdown than all the jobs related to hyderabad is displayed in the table,same for pune and other cities,so i have a rquirement in which if i apply on the job with location Hyderabad than email should be send to the hyderabad recruitment team and if i apply on the job with location Pune than email should send to the pune recruitment team ,below are the image for better understanding so how can i achieve this?actually i created a form and link this form to the table so when i click apply now button and fill the details of the form and click send button ,currently email sending both hyderabad and pune recruitment team so i want if a user select hyderabad than email should send hyderabad recruitment team same for pune,need any suggestion to achieve this because i am new in drupal7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKvDU.png)

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to create your form using [drupal 7 form api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x) if you didn't.

in modulename_yourform_submit function get value of selected city from $form_state, then using if statement check the value of city and send different email with [drupal mail function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7.x)